# zram-generator doesn't create zram device

Tags: memory, swap

I try to used [zram-generator](https://github.com/systemd/zram-generator) to create a zram device but it doesn't work.

I followed the steps listed in the *README.md* from the github repository.

- Install **zram-generator** using one of the methods listed above.
- Create a **zram-generator.conf** config file.
- Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to create new device units.
- Run `systemctl start /dev/zram0` (adjust the name as appropriate to match the config).
- Call `zramctl` or `swapon` to confirm that the device has been created and is in use.

1. I installed **zram-generator** using **cargo** with the command `cargo install zram-generator`
2. I created **zram-generator.conf** in **/etc/systemd/zram-generator.conf**

```ini
[zram0]
host-memory-limit = none
zram-size = min(ram / 2, 8192) # I have 16Go of RAM on my host
```

3. I ran `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Then I ran `systemctl start /dev/zram0` but it timeout after a while
5. `zramctl` return nothing and `swapon --show` return

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda4 partition  16G   0B   -2
```

Even a reboot changes nothing.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try with this conf instead ?

```
[zram0]
zram-size = ram / 2 
compression-algorithm = zstd
[zram1]
options = X-mount.mode=1777
mount-point = /var/compressed
```